# HTML table dynamically loads from a local CSV file, filter table using a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML table that is created dynamically from a local CSV table. I added a dropdown, wish I want to filter the table from unique elements from column 2. I am able to get the table to load, no problem, and the drop down also loads the unique values from the second column. I cannot get the "filtering" part to function. Any idea what I could be missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSV Table with Filter</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = null;

            // Function to filter the table based on the selected option
            function filterTable(selectedOption) {
                // Show all rows initially
                table.find("tr").show();

                // Hide rows that do not match the selected option
                if (selectedOption !== "All") {
                    table.find("tr:not(:has(th))").each(function() {
                        var cellValue = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
                        if (cellValue !== selectedOption) {
                            $(this).hide();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            // Load the CSV data and create the table
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "data/data.csv",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) {
                    var rows = data.split("\n");
                    table = $("<table />");
                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                        if (i === 0) {
                            var headerRow = $("<tr />");
                            for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                                headerRow.append($("<th />").text(cells[j]));
                            }
                            table.append(headerRow);
                        } else {
                            var row = $("<tr />");
                            for (var k = 0; k < cells.length; k++) {
                                row.append($("<td />").text(cells[k]));
                            }
                            table.append(row);
                        }
                    }
                    $("#csvTable").append(table);

                    // Populate the dropdown with unique values from the first column
                    var options = [];
                    table.find("tr:not(:has(th))").each(function() {
                        var cellValue = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();
                        if ($.inArray(cellValue, options) === -1) {
                            options.push(cellValue);
                        }
                    });
                    $("#filterSelect").append($("<option />").val("All").text("All"));
                    $.each(options, function(index, value) {
                        $("#filterSelect").append($("<option />").val(value).text(value));
                    });

                    // Add event listener to the dropdown
                    $("#filterSelect").change(function() {
                        filterTable($(this).val());
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label for="filterSelect">Filter by:</label>
        <select id="filterSelect"></select>
    </div>
    <div id="csvTable"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can get the table to load from the CSV file but cannot get the filtering to work.

Comment: I forgot to update: var cellValue = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
Once I change the eq(0) to eq(1), it works!

Comment: That was the first thing I noticed... "Didn't they say second column? It should be eq(1)"